# How to create anchor links using the id from each blog post?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I'm having some trouble with what I thought would be a simple problem.

I'd like to automate the creation of anchor links for a series of blog posts - I've been trying to use the **each()** command to loop through children in the parent div but I just can't get it working properly and am now so confused I don't know what I'm doing. ((@_@))

The blog content is structured like so:

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="list-journal-entry-wrapper">
  <div class="post-text">
    <div id="item101" class="journal-entry">...</div>
   </div><div class="post-text">
    <div id="item102" class="journal-entry">...</div>
   </div><div class="post-text">
    <div id="item103" class="journal-entry">...</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is use the unique item number (`id="item101"`) for each `.journal-entry` post to create a list of anchor links, like this:

```
<div id="news-links">
  <a href="#item101">Post 101</a><br/>
  <a href="#item102">Post 102</a><br/>
  <a href="#item103">Post 103</a><br/>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble finding the `id="xxxxx"` for each post:

Once I have that id, it should be pretty simple to write out anchor links using the `id` value as the `href`

`<a href="#xxxxx">Post xxxxx</a>`

I'd really appreciate an example so I can get my head around the **each()** command.

Or is there a better way to do this?

---

**Solved!** Thanks to examples from *adeneo* and *theCodeParadox*, I managed to learn a few things in the process and took a little from both solutions - in the interest of assisting others, here is my final completed solution as was used for my specific application:

http://jsfiddle.net/mDSWE/3/

Note there are additional divs in the actual HTML and the final jQuery routine looks for the article title `h2.title` to use as the link text and then using the `parents()` function, finds the id attribute of the first wrapper div `id="item12345"` which it uses for the anchor links `href`.

```
$('h2.title a').each(function() {
   var el = $(this);
    var id = el.parents('div.journal-entry:first').attr('id');
   var insert = '<a href="#' + id + '">' + el.text() + '</a></br>';
   $('#news-anchors').append(insert);
});
```

Working beautifully, so thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newsLinks = '<div id="news-links">';

$(".journal-entry").each(function(index, item) {
    newsLinks += '<a href="#'+item.id+'">Post '+item.id.replace('item', '')+'</a><br/>';
});

newsLinks += '</div>';
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XEFmq/)

It can also be done like so:

```
var newsLinks = '<div id="news-links">';

$.each($(".journal-entry"), function() {
    newsLinks += '<a href="#'+this.id+'">Post '+this.id.replace('item', '')+'</a><br/>';
});

newsLinks += '</div>';
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XEFmq/2/)

Comment: Instead of "function(index, item)" you could also rely do "function()" and rely on the "this" keyword: this.id and so on.

Comment: Yes, I know, but decided to use the index, item keywords to show how the each() function works. What the heck, I'll add a little more to show the each function used a little differently.

Comment: This has been most helpful! My feeble attempt was overly complex, this has been an eye-opener in simplifying my code, so thank you very much.

Comment: @Vee - Your welcome. If the answer solves your problem you should probably accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".journal-entry").each(function(index, value) {
  $('#news-links').append('<a href="#'+this.id+'">Post '+ this.id.replace('item', '')+'</a>');
});
```

Comment: This too, very helpful, since I anticipate using the index in other jQuery routines - nice to see it put so succinctly, thank you good sir.